# get a date from a mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a mysql database.
I have a php script, that connects to my database. My database consists of 3 tables, error, date, email address, as per the screenshot

[image: Database structure]

my php query is as follows:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("pmta_reporting") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM microcompany WHERE date='2013-01-28' AND code='2.0.0'") or die(mysql_error());
$count= mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I would like to replace '2013-01-28' with yesterdays date and in that format Y-m-d.
How can I do this?

Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Depending on your script you must choose either to use PHP generated date or MYSQL generated.. If you insert date generated from your PHP then generate date string in PHP and use it else you should use mysql date_sub function to get the correct date :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 day'));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM microcompany WHERE date='$yesterday' AND code='2.0.0'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No probs, happy to help, if your happy with it please make sure to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the MySQL function? They are meant to be used in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM microcompany WHERE date=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND code='2.0.0'
```

btw. mysql-* functions are deprecated: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, I tried that but for some reason does not work on my server.

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot to extract only the date from the function, see my updated answer.

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime('Yesterday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-28');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('Yesterday');
$fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $fdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

use native mysql functions for that purpose.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM microcompany WHERE
date=date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 day) AND code='2.0.0'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day',strtotime(date("y-m-d")) ));

$query = "SELECT * FROM microcompany WHERE date='".$yesterday."' AND code='2.0.0'";

$newQuery = 'update microcompany set date = "'.$yesterday.' where date = "'.$oldDate.'" and code ="2.0.0"';
?>
```